# Invoking Emacs command using key bound to it: How can I specify the optional parameter?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I have been trying to invoke the interactive lisp function `shell-command-on-region` which is bound to `M-|`. I'd like to know that how should I specify the 4th parameter, named `OUTPUT-BUFFER`, if I want to redirect the command's output?

My environment: 'Emacs25.2 + spacemacs' in MS Windows.

Comment: You would need to roll your own new function to query the user for additional arguments and then pass those arguments to the desired function -- e.g., `read-string`; `read-file-name`; `read-directory-name`; `read-number`; `read-passwd`; etc.  Alternatively, set up your own new function and hard-code the desired parameters/arguments.  I normally use `start-process` for just about everything, except for a few rare circumstances where I use `call-process`.  E.g. `(defun example () "Doc-string" (interactive) (let ((msg (read-string "Please type a string and press enter:  "))) (message "%s" msg)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  All I did was copy the `interactive` spec from `shell-command-on-region` and replace use of the prefix arg for argument `OUTPUT-BUFFER` with a buffer name that you input.

```el
(defun foo (start end command
            &optional output-buffer replace error-buffer display-error-buffer)
  (interactive
   (let (string buffer)
     (unless (mark)
       (error "The mark is not set now, so there is no region"))
     (setq string  (read-shell-command "Shell command on region: ")
           buffer  (read-buffer "Output buffer: "))
     (list (region-beginning) (region-end) string buffer
           current-prefix-arg shell-command-default-error-buffer t)))
  (shell-command-on-region start end command output-buffer
                           replace error-buffer display-error-buffer))
```

Comment: This function works. But how if I want to replace the region with the output of a command on it, just like the command `!!cmd` in _vim_?

Comment: `C-h f shell-command-on-region` answers that question. Just use `shell-command-on-region` with a prefix argument (`C-u`).